# how to inactive a link using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have jQuery site here. I have 4 links with in `ul` tag.  Within this link, I need to inactive a link but have to show. See below:

```
<div class="over hide"  id="waterSecondOver">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="current" id="chancingOverView">Overview</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="chancingLocalarea">Local Area</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="chancingFloorPlan">Floor Plans</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="chancingallery"  >Gallery</a>
</div>
```

I have a click function on the above links (except the 4th one i.e gallery). See the code

```
JQR('#waterSecondOver a').click(function() { 

    // my code

});
```

Here I need to show the gallery link, but nothing happens when click on the gallery (i.e must be inactive link or what I say it's functionality is only show the link as "gallery ")

I think it's clear . Please help me

Comment: Ermm... So don't make it change the gallery unless it's not a proper link?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's still not clear.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert Inactive some links but to show them!

Comment: Ah, silly me.  Couldn't be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

```
JQR('#waterSecondOver a').click(function(event) { 

event.preventDefault();

   });
```

Comment: The href for the links is javascript:void(0), so wouldn't the links already be doing nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Don't set hrefs in the anchor tags to `javascript:void(0);` - this is messy because it's needless repetition. With jQuery, it's possible to use `return false;` in your event callback to avoid the default click event taking you to a new page or the current one. While this is the easiest method, it's not always the best. See this article for more info:

http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

But you definitely don't want to be setting `href` manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way for simplicity...

```
JQR('#waterSecondOver a').click(function(event) { 

    if(JQR(this).attr('id') == "chancingallery"){
        // inactive all links except the one you dont want
      }else{
        // whatever you need....
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply change the class of the anchor(lets say class="active") and everytime onclick check for that "active" class. If the class is "active" do nothing else DO SOMETHING.